# Java Swing - Modify GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I got two JPanels in a GridBagLayout, a canvas and a toolbox, and if the user clicks over the toolbox panel I want it to change size (essentially opening it). Is there a (smarter) way to modify the weight of the toolbox constraint without having to remove all the components from the parent panel and re-adding the canvas and toolbox but with modified constraints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the constraints of a `Component` already contained in a `Container` with a `GridBagLayout` by calling

1. [setConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#setConstraints(java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.GridBagConstraints)) on the `GridBagLayout` with the appropriate `GridBagConstraint` object
2. Calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on the `Container`